# pip uninstall tensorflow throws _csv.Error: line contains NUL

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip

```
C:\Users\Asish>pip uninstall tensorflow
Found existing installation: tensorflow 1.15.0
ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\asish\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\base_command.py", line 186, in _main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "c:\users\asish\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\uninstall.py", line 79, in run
    auto_confirm=options.yes, verbose=self.verbosity > 0,
  File "c:\users\asish\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\req\req_install.py", line 686, in uninstall
    uninstalled_pathset = UninstallPathSet.from_dist(dist)
  File "c:\users\asish\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\req\req_uninstall.py", line 535, in from_dist
    for path in uninstallation_paths(dist):
  File "c:\users\asish\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\req\req_uninstall.py", line 67, in unique
    for item in fn(*args, **kw):
  File "c:\users\asish\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\req\req_uninstall.py", line 86, in uninstallation_paths
    for row in r:
_csv.Error: line contains NUL
```

pip uninstall TensorFlow throws this error. BTW current version of TensorFlow installed shows this same error when imported. tensorflow==1.15.0

Also when I use pip freeze > requirements.txt 
it shows this warning and terminal text changes to yellow color,
I don't know if they are connected

````
WARNING: Could not generate requirement for distribution -pencv-python 4.1.1.26 (c:\users\asish\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages): Parse error at "'-pencv-p'": Expected W:(abcd...)```
````

Comment: I have the same issue with the package "scipy". Very strange behaviour...