# cant uninstall numpy on windows

Tags: python, pip

i just want to uninstall numpy using

```
pip uninstall numpy
```

but it gives me the following error

```
ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\dmits\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\base_command.py", line 160, in exc_logging_wrapper
    status = run_func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\dmits\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\uninstall.py", line 98, in run
    uninstall_pathset = req.uninstall(
  File "C:\Users\dmits\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\req\req_install.py", line 659, in uninstall
    uninstalled_pathset = UninstallPathSet.from_dist(dist)
  File "C:\Users\dmits\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\req\req_uninstall.py", line 526, in from_dist
    for path in uninstallation_paths(dist):
  File "C:\Users\dmits\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\req\req_uninstall.py", line 45, in unique
    for item in fn(*args, **kw):
  File "C:\Users\dmits\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\req\req_uninstall.py", line 85, in uninstallation_paths
    for entry in entries:
  File "C:\Users\dmits\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\metadata\base.py", line 472, in <genexpr>
    return (str(pathlib.Path(row[0])) for row in csv.reader(text.splitlines()))
_csv.Error: line contains NUL
```

can anybody help? btw the command is written in terminal

Comment: This [has been reported before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62243351/pip-uninstall-tensorflow-throws-csv-error-line-contains-nul) for other packages, but not with any solutions or explanations that I can find.

Comment: yes i searched for other people who had the same question but i was never able to find any solution that worked for me. thanks for your insights though

Comment: Are you running this on a cmd window with Administrator rights?

Comment: yes by the way dont worry i fixed it by uninstalling python through the control panel and installing it again which was kind of a pain but i fixed it now